# "GetxController" not found. You need to call "Get.put(XXXX)" or "Get.lazyPut(()=> XXXX)"

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I encountered a strange problem. There was no exception in my local debugging, but a gray interface appeared online. I initialized it and thought that Getx could not find the corresponding GetxController.

The phenomenon of the problem is: no error will be reported when entering the page for the first time, but an error will be reported after entering the page for the second time. And when you call Get.back() to return to the previous level, an error will be reported only if you enter again. If you return by sliding sideways, no error will be reported.

If Get.back() returns to the upper-level page, waits for 1~2 seconds, and then enters again, no error will be reported. Have you ever encountered such a magical problem? I'm not sure if it has something to do with the life cycle.

My code doesn't have much logic. My UI interface hierarchy is like this. Class A is the parent view, classes B, C, and D are subviews (separately encapsulated). Then I put a view model in A and find it in B, C, and D.

Comment: add your code to the question

Comment: Thank you for seeing the question and replying to me, but I'm sorry, I can't provide the code (confidential). What I can describe can only be in my text. I don't know what other information you need. I hope I can try my best. supply

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue when using Getx as you state management.
So what is happening over here is that the dependency injection is not happening correctly, to fix so you can wrap your scaffold with getBuilder and init it with the controller, example below:

```
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import '../controller/example_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class exampleView extends GetView<exampleController> {
  const exampleView({super.key});
  @override

//Refer this section
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder(
        init: exampleontroller(),
        builder: (exampleController controller) {
          return Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "What's Included?",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 15,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'Trying',
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 24,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

this might solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing any code. But I think what happens is that the controller got disposed off when navigating to another route/page. What can help then is to use a `lazyPut` in combination with `fenix: true`. This way it can be restored after it was disposed. So instead of

```
Get.put(MyController());
```

or

```
Get.lazyPut(() => MyController());
```

do this instread:

```
Get.lazyPut(() => MyController(), fenix: true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This Type of error usually occurs when you try to get "GetXControoller" controller without definning it.**
For example:

```
final MYGetController controller = Get.find();
```

First you need to initialize it

```
final controller = Get.put(MYGetController);
```